# Why are subfolders not being seen by the Git repository?

Tags: xcode, git, repository, subdirectory

I have just created a local repository (using Git) for a project that will contain many subfolders (it is a pedagogical project with Lesson 1...2...3 etc..., each one with a folder within the main directory).
I connected this to the remote repository I created on GitHub.com and hoped that would have been enough to start working, pushing, committing etc... now that I have created the first Xcode project inside the main folder neither Xcode Commit function nor Terminal `git commit` command is seeing any change.
The symptoms I see are that the remote repository sees "Project name" folder, then "Lesson 1" folder inside it but nothing else inside "Lesson 1", where the Xcode project should be (it actually is there in the Finder).
What may have gone wrong?
What would have been the proper set of actions to create a repository in a directory that would automatically fetch every new file added to it?
Thank you so much!

Comment: When you do git status, what does it say?

Comment: It used to say "nothing to commit", as if it didn't see the extra files. I tried to go around it, cancelling everything, creating the repository on GitHub.com, then cloning it to the Mac, and then starting to add things in there and now it seems better. But is that the correct way? Or is there any other way?

Comment: You should have been able to start everything locally but without the details when you did that, it is hard to identify why you had the issue.

Comment: I did this: `cd <topFolder>`, then `git init`, then `git remote add origin <repoURL>` and then started adding files normally. `status` & `commit` didn't seem to like this.

Comment: That all seems correct. After that a bunch of git adds and commit should do it.

Comment: I was trying with `git add .` but it was telling me there was nothing to add ... sometimes it's just better to start over from scratch. Thank you for your support!

Comment: To see if you have nested repositories (i.e., XCode made extra ones), run `find . -name .git -print` (the `-print` is the default, but I like to use it). Based on a quick google search it looks like the default is for XCode to make its own repository, and it's not possible to put a repository *in* a repository, so this "hides" the XCode repo from the outer repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git will not automatically track new files you create in the directory tree which contains your local git repo.

When you create new files, you need to inform git that you want them tracked, with the "git add" command.

> git add path-to-new-file

If you create new files and do not add them, then when you run the "git status" command the output should contain a section labeled Untracked files, like this:

> Untracked files:
> (use "git add ..." to include in what will be
> committed)
>
> asdf.txt

It will show the path to the file(s) relative to the top of your git repo, including the filename(s).  Pass all of that to the git add command. Then commit, just as you would for changed files.